# Laravel Url won't work for two different files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am working with Laravel on a homestead box. I have created two files under resources>views>profile (index.blade.php & pic.blade.php).

I am having trouble making the link for the image work across both files

```
<img src="{{url('../')}}/public/img/{{Auth::user()->pic}}" width="100px" height="100px" /><br>

<img src="{{url('../')}}/img/{{Auth::user()->pic}}" width="100px" height="100px" /><br>
```

each of these work but one will only display the image for one page at a time. I'm sure it has something to do with the path and the homestead environment, but not really sure.

Comment: Where the image is stored ?

Comment: Basically when registering for a profile the default images come from /myappname/public/img however once the user updates/changes the profile picture, the pictures should store in the database under users.pic.

Answer (score 2):

Your images seems to be stored in `/public/img`, you could use the helper `asset()`

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/'.auth()->user()->pic) }}" width="100px" height="100px" /><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of live deployed system,  you should use

```
<img src="{{url('/img/'.Auth::user()->pic)}}" width="100px" height="100px" /><br>
```

Or if it is just a normal local server  with /public included in URL

```
<img src="{{url('/public/img/'.Auth::user()->pic)}}" width="100px" height="100px" /><br>
```

this should generate URL to img folder which is accessible publically